# Lost Lydia, i think she fell off a cliff

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I seem to have lost my companion Lydia, i noticed she was gone after a big battle but i couldn't find her corpse anywhere, so i assume she fell of the bridges into the canyons at the sorcerer academy place.

Is there anyway to get her back? the save has already been overwritten

Comment: @Assylum Thx for that o so useful comment..
@PrivatePansy; I never got a msg saying my follower left me, she just dissapeared.. i looked at other questions but none resembled my situation.

Comment: @Vahx It is the only helpful advice in this case. XBOX has no console access, on PC it would've been possible to resurrect her. You might think it is rude, but it is the only advice that I can give here.

Comment: It's not helpful advice to someone who plays the game on an xbox, looking for help with their xbox game.

Comment: @TZHX The helpful part was that it is not possible. There is nothing you can do, except load an older save. Since the only save was overwritten, confirmed by the OP, it is the unfortunate truth.

Comment: @TZHX answers should be helpful to everybody with a similar problem, not just the OP. Whether OP can use console commands or not, somebody else might, so there's no reason not to include them in an answer.

Comment: @kotekzot I agree, but telling the OP that 'you should play on PC' is not helpful either.

Comment: @TZHX ah, I couldn't see the comment you were responding to and misunderstood your objection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If she has died, then there is unfortunately no way to get her back.

However, she may just have gotten lost. If that is the case, she should return to either the castle in Whiterun or one of your purchased houses after several game days.

Comment: ok thank you, i'll look in a few hours to see if i can find her somewhere. going to miss her if she is dead, she was a good tank.